# Append to C String Based on User Input

Tags: c, string, char

I would like to receive an integer *x* via user input, and return a string with length *x* in '#'s.

i.e. 
    *x* = 4

⇒ "####"

Is a simple solution possible, along the lines of:

```
printf( "%c * x = %c", hash, x, hash*x);
```

Currently, my online findings have me creating an iterative program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//function creates xhash with width '#' characters 
void append( char* xhash, char hash, int x )
{
    int i = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < x; i++ )    {  xhash[i] = hash;  }
    xhash[x] = '\0';
}

int main ( void )
{
    int x = 0;
    scanf( "%d", &x );

    char xhash[250] = ""; 
    char hash = "#";

    append( xhash, hash, x );

    printf( "%c", xhash );

    return 0;
}
```

And this gives me a strange design: ▒

I find C strings very confusing, coming from Python where I would use

```
str.append(i)
```

or

```
str = "#" * x
```

Comment: Are you after a recursive solution?

Comment: Recursion would be fine. My problem though is that I don't understand how to manipulate strings in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C does not have a full-fledged string data type.  "C strings" are just contiguous sequences if `char` values, terminated by a character with value `0` (which can be spelled `'\0'`).

Very important to your question, though, is that (1) `char` is an integer data type, (2) different delimiters are used for string literals than for (single-)`char` literals, and (3) string literals evaluate to *pointers* to the first character of a C string.

Thus, this ...

```
char hash = "#";
```

... attempts to store a pointer in `hash`, probably resulting in the last byte of the pointer value.  Instead, you want this:

```
char hash = '#';
```

Moreover, to print a C string via one of the `printf()`-family functions, you want to use edit descriptor `%s`:

```
printf("%s", xhash);
```

Descriptor `%c` is for outputting a single character.

Answer (score 0):

A string in C is just an array of bytes followed by a zero byte. That is all that they are.

For a function that creates a string you have two options. You can have the caller pass in a pointer to an array (and the array size, if you're smart) and the function fills it in. The second option is to `malloc` inside your function and return the pointer to the caller.

Another thing to remember is the standard C library. Your `append` function is essentially `memset` followed by setting a zero at the end. You should just call memset instead of doing your own loop.

And I think you are getting weird output because the printf format for a string is `%s` not `%c`. The `%c` format is for a single character.

Finally if you are unfamiliar with C programming you should be compiling will all warnings turned on. The compiler warnings would have told you about the bad printf format string and the invalid `char` assignment.